# Deixar uma opção fixa numa tabela dinâmica - JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho uma tabela dinâmica, que muda de acordo com o select do usuário feito em HTML. 
Porém, toda vez que a página atualiza a opção selecionada acaba mudando também.

Eu pensei em duas possibilidades que talvez daria certo para o que eu quero:

- Criar uma variável e passar a escolha atual para essa variável. Criar um botão chamado de "Carregar" e toda vez que esse botão for acionado, ele carregará o que estiver dentro dessa variável;
- Melhor forma: criar uma opção default e ir atualizando essa opção default de acordo com a escolha do usuário.

A primeira opção eu até consegui fazer, mas ele continua "atualizando" a página e perdendo o valor.

Aqui tem o exemplo do código:
http://jsfiddle.net/kBQdS/247/

Obrigado,

Answer (score 1):

para tal, armazene o valor do `select` no `localStorage`, ao carregar a pagina, atualize o valor do `select` e chame o evento `change`.

```
var dynamicTable = (function() {
    ...
})();

$(document).ready(function(e) {        
    var data1 = [...];        
    var data2 = [...];        
    var dt = dynamicTable.config(...);        

    $('.montadoras').change(function() {
        localStorage.setItem('montadoras_value', this.value);
        ...
    });

    var montadoraAtual = localStorage.getItem('montadoras_value');
    $('.montadoras').val(montadoraAtual).trigger("change");
});
```

Comment: Obrigado Tobias, a ideia deu certo sim. O problema é que como são várias pessoas preenchendo o mesmo formulário, se um atualiza, acaba atualizando todos. Dá pra fazer alguma coisa nesse sentido onde cada formulário seja único?

Comment: @user2287892 o localStorage existe apenas no cliente (Browser) e não pode ser acessado no servidor, então se as pessoas estiverem usando computadores diferentes, então eles estaram isolados. Se mais de uma pessoa usar o mesmo computador e browser, você terá que adicionar uma chave única ao nome do registro no localStorage, como um email... eg: localStorage("tobias@me.com", valor).

Comment: O form é acessado via servidor, ou seja, ele acaba pegando o localStorage do mesmo lugar. Mas não daria pra criar um array como chave unica ou não é permitido?

Comment: Só complementando, eu tenho um ID que é único para cada formulário. Como eu poderia usar ele ao meu favor, ou seja, armazenar o localStorage dentro desse ID, como chave unica?

Comment: Dei uma evoluída na minha questão, estou conseguindo trazer o número gerado automaticamente pelo formulário como "key" (consigo visualizar através do console), o problema que toda vez que eu atualizo a página, ele perde a informação. Isso não estava acontecendo antes.

        var nsit = document.getElementById("nsit").value;                   
 localStorage.setItem(nsit, this.value);


        var montadoraAtual = localStorage.getItem('nsit');
        $('.montadoras').val(montadoraAtual).trigger("change");

O que pode estar errado?

Comment: @user2287892 você está passando a `string 'nsit'` e não a `variavel nsit` para o `localStorage.getItem(nsit)`.

Comment: Agora deu tudo certo. Além do que você comentou, precisei colocar var nsit = document.getElementById("nsit").value; fora da $('.montadoras').change(function() 

Obrigado pela ajuda